# Problema con destructuracion y forEach

Tags: reactjs, api, foreach

estoy intentando mostrar por pantalla toda una lista que obtengo de una [API](https://pokeapi.co/), me entere que para mostrar toda la lista con un forEach primero tengo que destructurar, entonces me quedo algo asi

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class HomeContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151&offset=151') //Solicitud api
            .then(({result}) => {
              //  console.log('aaa', result.data.results[0])

                crearCarta({result})
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error) //Solicitud error
            })
    }


    render() { //Renderizamos el html
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="navbar"></div>
            <header id="container"></header>
            </div>
            );
    }

}
function crearCarta({pokemons}) {
    console.log('Dentro de Crear Carta -->   ', pokemons)
    const container = document.getElementById('container')
    console.log( 'Llamado a la API dentro de crearCarta' ,pokemons)

    console.log(' aaa ', {pokemons})
        pokemons.forEach(id => {
        container.innerHTML += 
        ` 
        <header id="container">
        <h1>${pokemons}</h1>
        </header> 
        `
    }); 
}



export default HomeContainer
```

Pero no se como hacer para mostrar ahora por consola el result, antes lo hacia con

```
console.log(result)
```

pero ahora no puedo hacerlo con nada, y no se como hacer para que me funcione el forEach.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado, `axios` te devuelve dentro de la propiedad `data` el resultado de tu petición. Por el otro, el api que estás usando retorna la lista de pokemons dentro de la propiedad `results` así que la forma para acceder a esa lista desde el response sería `response.data.results`. Lo siguiente que necesitas hacer es guardar esa lista dentro del estado del componente para que la puedas usar luego para renderizar la lista de pokemons dentro de tu app, dicho esto te quedaría algo como esto:

```
axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151&offset=151')
  .then(({ data }) => {
    const { results } = data;

    this.setState({
      pokemons: results
    });
  })
```

Al guardar en el estado del componente puedes acceder a la lista que te devolvió la api por medio de `this.state.pokemons`, por lo que lo único que te quedaría por hacer iterar esa lista a través de un `forEach` o un `map` (preferiblemente) en tu función `render`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="navbar"></div>
      <div id="container">
        {this.state.pokemons.map(pokemon => (
          <h1>{pokemon.name}</h1>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

PD: Recuerda inicializar la propiedad `pokemons` dentro del estado del componente en la función `constructor` para evitar errores `this.state = { pokemons: [] }`.

:)

Comment: Osea que lo deberia hacer sin una funcion lo de mostrar los pokemons?

Comment: Así es! La forma correcta de hacerlo es a través del estado del componente. Puedes echar un vistazo a la [documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) oficial.

Comment: Gracias!, estoy intentando resolver un error que me dice que "pokemons is null", dentro del return, estoy hace tiempo y no puedo, tenes alguna idea?

Comment: Ya lo inicializaste en el constructor? Ya verificaste que en el state `pokemons` tenga datos? Necesitaría mas información para ayudarte, puedes subir el código a un editor online?

Comment: https://codepen.io/eliiansito01/pen/BaWQgqw    Mira, me quede un poco distraido intentando realizar los detalles de los errores como lo decia la documentacion, me distraje con eso, pero todavia no puedo hacer que ande

Comment: Por cierto @guadamuzjj, estuve intentando probar algo con useState pero no me sirvio, me olvide de borrarlo por completo cuando comparti el codigo, pido disculpas

Comment: Estoy leyendo la documentacion de constructor, pero no comprendo como inicializar mi variable pokemon ahi dentro, debo usar constructor(pokemon) ?

Comment: Dos cosas, la función constructor no la habías escrito y en el render `this.state.pokemon` no existe es `pokemons` en plural, esta es mi versión https://codepen.io/guadamuzjj/pen/wvJoLVy

Comment: Dios! era tal cual habia leido en la documentacion eso me pasa por no intentar hacerlo aunque lo lea, pense que constructor tenia que cambiarlo por otro nombre y bla bla, no se bien en que afecta ponerle el constructor realmente, si podes sacarme esa duda estaria genial!, yo mientras tanto voy a seguir practicando dia y noche con otras API hasta poder hacer todo del tiron, muchisimas gracias realmente me salvaste.

Comment: Podrías marcar mi respuesta como aceptada? Gracias!

Comment: Hola @guadamuzjj, disculpame denuevo la molestia, estoy intentando entrar al codepen.io que pasaste ayer pero no me deja, creo que lo eliminaste, no te quedo guardado o algo como para pasarmelo por chat? Gracias!

Comment: Lo acabo de habilitar.